# Git revert explanation

Tags: git, git-revert

Reading online, I understand the git revert cancels a single commit from the past, but I am unclear as to what that means unless the cancelled commit is the last commit performed.

For example, observe the following three versions of a file:

> "a" => "aa" => "a|a"

If I reverted the 2nd version, what would the 4th version look like? "|a" or "a|"?

Comment: `git revert` doesn't affect previous commits.  It creates a *new* commit.  I suggest reading this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/

Comment: You are right, I updated the question. I read the relevant section in this tutorial and it made me ask this question.

Comment: Ok.  I don't understand the notation in your question though, is that the literal content of the file?  (FWIW, you could just try it to find out what happens.)

Comment: I updated the question again, and added quotation marks around the strings. The point is that it is ambiguous whether I added the a to the right or left of the original a, and reverting that commit would have to pick one of them to be removed. (Since the results would be different in the rightmost a was removed than if the leftmost a was)

Comment: You should really just give it a try...

Comment: I got a conflict. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revert work by creating a patch which is the opposite of the changes introduced in the commit you want to revert and try to apply it, then create a commit.

If the patch do not apply due to some changes introduced by commits in between, you will have to resolve conflicts...

I hope it will help you better understand how it works.

PS: your notation won't help to understand and explain how revert works because changes are at line level and not file one...